# Updating state repeatedly - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Hi I have a parent component, having two child component as follows, Child1 has draggable div element, which on drag gives value out to Parent component which then I have to pass to Child2 and utilise, but before utilising it in Child2 I have to make a dozens of calculations.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [dragValue, setDragValue] = useState(0);
  const dragHanlder = (dragVal) => {
     setDragValue(dragVal);
  };
  return (
        <Child1 mouseDrag={dragHanlder} />
        <Child2 dragValue={dragValue}/>
  );
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
   state = {
     afterCalculationsVal: 0
   };
   componentDidUpdate = () => {
      const { dragValue } = this.props;
      const someFinalval = val //this val takes dragValue applies checks, calculations and conditions and finally gives out some value
      this.setState({afterCalculationsVal: someFinalval });
   };

   render() {
      const { afterCalculationsVal } = this.state;
      return (
         <Child3 afterCalculationsVal={afterCalculationsVal} >
      );
   }
}
```

Problem is I'm getting maximum depth reached issue, because I'm setting state for drag which is continuous. Is there any way I can overcome this. I cannot use the 'dragValue' coming in props in Child2 directly, the calculations on the props value is mandatory, and I have to set state after that.

Comment: Generally speaking when you want to calculate a value based off of props that you pass in, you want to do it within your render() method as a "computed property" instead of setting it to state. In this situation, you have basically created an infinite loop. componentDidUpdate will be called every single time the component updates which includes setting state. Since you aren't doing any checks in your componentDidUpdate prior to setting state, you are getting this maximum depth exceeded as that setState is making the component immediately call componentDidUpdate again. and then again. and again

Comment: "You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop"

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: The problem is due to setState in componentDidUpdate which is causing infinite loop. Other than that you can use debouncing on drag handler which would lead to lower number of rerenders of child2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the component updates it is going into componentDidUpdate then setting state causing another update. Setting an if condition checking drag value should fix your problem.

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    const { dragValue } = this.props;
    if(prevState.dragValue !== prevState.dragValue){
      // Will only re-render when dragValue changes
      const someFinalval = val 
      this.setState({afterCalculationsVal: someFinalval });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use this.setState in the componentdidupdate without checking the value that you change are really changed. Infact this trigger an infinit loop

```
componentDidUpdate = () => {
      const { dragValue } = this.props;
      const someFinalval = val //this val takes dragValue applies checks, calculations and conditions and finally gives out some value
      if(/** your check *//)
      this.setState({afterCalculationsVal: someFinalval });
   };
```